# NSManagedObjectID into NSData

Tags: cocoa, core-data, save

I found this wonderful NSManagedObjectID. This would be very good for referencing an Entity/NSManagedObject/NSEntityDescription, right?
Let's get an ID from an entity:

```
NSEntityDescription *entity = [self newEntity];     
NSManagedObjectID *objID = [entity objectID];
```

So... any idea how to get this `objID` into a string? Or better: NSData. Actually something to be able to save it to the NSUserDefaults. ;-)

Btw: NSFetchRequest doesn't want to work in my case. I use an modified version of this example: [answer of an old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499897/save-coredata-entities-in-nsuserdefaults).

Answer (score 39, accepted):

To get an archived URI corresponding to a `NSManagedObject`'s `objectID`:

```
NSManagedObject* myMO;
...
NSURL *uri = [[myMO objectID] URIRepresentation];
NSData *uriData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:uri];
```

In order to get back to an instance of the original managed object, you need a CoreData stack with the persistent store holding that instance *already added* to the `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`. Then:

```
NSData *uriData;
NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *psc;
NSManagedObjectContext *moc; //with moc.persistentStoreCoordinator = psc.
...
NSURL *uri = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:uriData];
NSManagedObjectID *moID = [psc managedObjectIDForURIRepresentation:uri];
NSManagedObject *myMO = [moc objectWithID:moID];
```

Answer (score 5):

From the NSManagedObjectID [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectID_Class/Reference/NSManagedObjectID.html):

> Object IDs can be transformed into a
>   URI representation which can be
>   archived and recreated later to refer
>   back to a given object (using
>   managedObjectIDForURIRepresentation:
>   (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator) and
>   objectWithID:
>   (NSManagedObjectContext). For example,
>   the last selected group in an
>   application could be stored in the
>   user defaults through the group
>   object’s ID. You can also use object
>   ID URI representations to store “weak”
>   relationships across persistent stores
>   (where no hard join is possible).

Just turn it into a URL then turn that into a string or a data.

Answer (score 3):

Did you look at [URIRepresentation](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectID_Class/Reference/NSManagedObjectID.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObjectID/URIRepresentation)? It's easy to convert an NSURL to an NSString, and that to an NSData.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to convert the NSURL into an NSString before archiving.  Just archive the NSURL.

Edit: I've recently learned that an object's ID can change, such as after a migration. It therefore seems like not a good idea to save an ID to disk expecting to be able to reference the object later.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the cleanest and shortest way I've found to do this currently, using the `setURL` and `getURL` methods added in 4.0 to avoid extra calls to `NSKeyedUnarchiver` and `NSKeyedArchiver`:

**Setter:**

```
 + (void)storeSomeObjectId:(NSManagedObjectID *)objectId
 {
     [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setURL:[objectId URIRepresentation] 
                                            forKey:@"someObjectIdKey"];
     [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
 }
```

**Getter:**

```
 + (SomeManagedObject *)getObjectByStoredId
 {
     NSURL *uri = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] URLForKey:@"someObjectIdKey"];
     NSManagedObjectID *objectId = [self.persistentStoreCoordinator managedObjectIDForURIRepresentation:uri];
     SomeManagedObject *object = [self.managedObjectContext objectWithID:objectId];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

As @preston said, don't save an objectID to disk, instead:

1. Make a new attribute on your entity called "id"
2. Make a new attribute on your entitys parent entity called "myEntitysMaxId"
3. Override your entitys parent implementation "addNewMyEntityObject:"
4. There, increase "myEntitysMaxId" and set that value as the new entitys "id"
5. Do as you normally do when you fetch an entity based on its attributes!

Much cleaner and better!